# Is there any way for creating Mongo codecs automatically?

Tags: java, mongodb, asynchronous, codec

I'm willing to migrate my code from mongojack to something that supports the new async mongo driver. Yet I find that the new way of encoding/decoding is through `Codec`s and I don't see myself writing a `Codec` for every class in my model. That's why I'd rather write a lib that given a class creates a `Codec`. However I don't know how, nor do I know if there's already some effort out there trying to achieve the same.
Are there some libs that achieve what I want? if not, what's the best approach to achieve it.

(I know I should probably use `CodecProvider` somewhere in there, but I still don't know where to start)

Comment: I'm not sure what the codecs do, but have you looked at the Spring Data mappers?

Comment: I have indeed, but it's not what I need. The new mongo java driver (version 3+),  gives us the chance to parse the response directly to our domain classes without using intermediate representations (DBObject), through Codecs. Yet you have to write them yourself (http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/bson/codecs/). I'm looking for some library that writes those Codecs automatically, so I don't have to do it manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you use Jackson you can use the mongo-jackson-codec from https://github.com/ylemoigne/mongo-jackson-codec which will handle it automatically for you.

Comment: Word of warning: as of the time of this writing (on 2016-10-04) this mongo-jackson-codec library suffers a severe drawback in that it can only bridge the gap between mongo codecs and jackson via full documents, i.e. it cannot serialize non-document BSON values at the root level. This limitation will come into play when trying to use the Jackson codec to serialize values like `java.time.Instant` when building query `Bson` documents in your `find` or `update` command (when using the native Mongo Java drivers).

Answer (score 5):

Here's how we address this (end result is super slick between Lombok, Jackson and MongoDB):

Provider:

```
public class JacksonCodecProvider implements CodecProvider {
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public JacksonCodecProvider(final ObjectMapper bsonObjectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = bsonObjectMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> Codec<T> get(final Class<T> type, final CodecRegistry registry) {

            return new JacksonCodec<>(objectMapper, registry, type);

    }
}
```

And the Codec itself:

```
class JacksonCodec<T> implements Codec<T> {
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    private final Codec<RawBsonDocument> rawBsonDocumentCodec;
    private final Class<T> type;

    public JacksonCodec(ObjectMapper objectMapper,
                        CodecRegistry codecRegistry,
                        Class<T> type) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
        this.rawBsonDocumentCodec = codecRegistry.get(RawBsonDocument.class);
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public T decode(BsonReader reader, DecoderContext decoderContext) {
        try {

            RawBsonDocument document = rawBsonDocumentCodec.decode(reader, decoderContext);
            String json = document.toJson();
            return objectMapper.readValue(json, type);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void encode(BsonWriter writer, Object value, EncoderContext encoderContext) {
        try {

            String json = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(value);

            rawBsonDocumentCodec.encode(writer, RawBsonDocument.parse(json), encoderContext);

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Class<T> getEncoderClass() {
        return this.type;
    }
}
```

When combined with Lombok and the latest Jackson annotations, it allows us to do stuff like this (hardly looks like Java code, eh?):

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
@JsonDeserialize(builder = Account.AccountBuilder.class)
@Builder(toBuilder=true)
@Value
public class Account {

    @JsonProperty private String _id;
    @JsonProperty private long _version;
    @JsonProperty private String organizationName;

    @JsonPOJOBuilder(withPrefix = "")
    public static final class AccountBuilder {
    }

}
```

Then:

```
Account account = collection.find(eq("_id", id)).first();
System.out.println(account.getOrganizationName());
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Isn't this a good candidate for being packaged up and distributed via Maven? I've not been able to find an available equivalent.