# MongoDB casting documents into custom types

Tags: java, mongodb, serialization, deserialization, mongodb-java

Is there some way to read from MongoDB values to objects of my type, without converting them from SimpleDBObject?

I have tried to get all documents from collection with `coll.find()` but when I iterate through them I get

> Can't find a codec for interface com.mynamespace.models.interfaces.Profile.

What's the correct way? I use standard Java driver.

As far as i remember in C# and Couchbase i was simply writing/reading documents into my custom types. What's the way here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something that I have used in the past is [Mongo Jack](http://mongojack.org/). This provides a simple wrapper that, according to their documentation, directly maps POJOs from the Mongo stream, without the intermediary SimpleDBObject. This also uses the Jackson library, so you can use Jackson serialization and de-serialization annotations.

This is what the website says:

> Deserialises queried objects directly from the MongoDB stream, making it one of the (if not the) fastest object mappers for MongoDB out there.

Perhaps this is what you are looking for, yes?

Here's the example from the website:

```
JacksonDBCollection<MyObject, String> coll = JacksonDBCollection.wrap(dbCollection, MyObject.class,
        String.class);
MyObject myObject = ...
WriteResult<MyObject, String> result = coll.insert(myObject);
String id = result.getSavedId();
MyObject savedObject = coll.findOneById(id);
```

Comment: yes, somethin like that. So, am i right there is nothin like direct serialization/deserialization in Mongo+Java combination? without 3rd party libs i mean

Comment: @ArkadyB according to the description on the website, they do deserialize directly from the Mongo stream, from the website: "Deserialises queried objects directly from the MongoDB stream, making it one of the (if not the) fastest object mappers for MongoDB out there" - Mongo Jack website

Comment: @ArkadyB Yes, I included one in my answer, though if you're looking for more, you might want to try the [tutorial](http://mongojack.org/tutorial.html) on the website.

Comment: thanks for advise! Now the next question is.. Since this is 3rd party library, what is faster - write custom from/to SimpleDBObject converters for each class or use Jackson`s lib? I was hoping there is default approach in Mongo/Java case without need to use somethin else...

Comment: I'm not quite sure about which is faster. Using the dependency will increase project size, but as for speed, it would seem something that serializing directly from the stream, as does Mongo Jack, would be faster than writing your own object converters after it has already been written to the SimpleDBObject. Mongo Jack writes directly to your POJO

Answer (score 0):

The new [Codec](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.0/bson/codecs/) infrastructure in the mongo-java-driver >= 3.0 pretty much does what you want. You do have to create the Codecs manually, but there have also been a few efforts to [create codecs automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32417267/is-there-any-way-for-creating-mongo-codecs-automatically).

There are also other full-blown ODM frameworks out there such as Morphia and Spring Data MongoDB.

Answer (score 0):

[Morphia](http://mongodb.github.io/morphia/) is the officially supported ODM for MongoDB and Java.  Custom codecs can be written for your Java objects so that the serialization would be largely transparent to your application.  Spring data and mongojack are also great choices.  Spring-data is actively maintained though I'm not entirely sure how active mongojack is being developed these days.